# Checking user authentication via angular, node and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have performed user authentication using Node(Passport.js) and mongoDB. It worked well.

Now am adding angular as front-end.

I am posting user credentials from angular to node api to get back the response as "Success" or "Failure" but not getting any response.

Below are the code:

**ANGULAR PART:**

**app.component.html:**

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ngModel>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ngModel>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

</form>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from 
      '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {};
    onSubmit(loginForm) {
       console.log(loginForm.value);
       let url = 'http://localhost:8080/login';
       this.httpClient.post(url, {loginForm(loginForm)},{responseType: 
           'text'}).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
    }
}
```

**NODE PART:**

**routes.js:**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err,user) {
    if(err) {
        return err;
    }
    if(!user) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return user;
    }
}));
```

**passport.js:**

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, email, password, done) { 
    var newUser = new User();
    User.findOne({ 'email' :  email}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        if (!user || !newUser.validatePassword(req.body.password, 
                 user.password)) {
            return done(null, false);
        } 
        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

Now the request from angular goes to node api "http://localhost:8080/login" but I didn't get any response from node side.

Need someone's help to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of send loginForm.value as a request body.

Comment: @SantoshSingh pls tell how to do that

Comment: I think You had taken the reference of this link https://www.djamware.com/post/5a878b3c80aca7059c142979/securing-mean-stack-angular-5-web-application-using-passport for creating application